# Flex: How do you validate 2 password fields to make sure they match?

Tags: apache-flex, validation

I want to use a validator to ensure 2 password fields match in Flex. I want the validator to highlight form fields like a normal flex validation control. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`enter code here`I created my own custom validator (mostly copied from date validator):

```
package validators
{
    import mx.validators.ValidationResult;
    import mx.validators.Validator;

    public class PasswordValidator extends Validator
    {
        // Define Array for the return value of doValidation().
        private var results:Array;

        public function PasswordValidator()
        {
            super();
        }

        public var confirmationSource: Object;
        public var confirmationProperty: String;

        // Define the doValidation() method.
        override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {

            // Call base class doValidation().
            var results:Array = super.doValidation(value.password);

            if (value.password != value.confirmation) {
                results.push(new ValidationResult(true, null, "Mismatch",
                "Password Dosen't match Retype!"));

            }

            return results;
        }       

        /**
         *  @private
         *  Grabs the data for the confirmation password from its different sources
         *  if its there and bundles it to be processed by the doValidation routine.
         */
        override protected function getValueFromSource():Object
        {
            var value:Object = {};

            value.password = super.getValueFromSource();

            if (confirmationSource && confirmationProperty)
            {
                value.confirmation = confirmationSource[confirmationProperty];
            }

            return  value;
        }       

    }
}
```

the example mxml for using:

```
<validators:PasswordValidator id="pwvPasswords" required="true" source="{txtPassword}" property="text" confirmationSource="{txtPasswordConfirm}" confirmationProperty="text" trigger="{btnStep2Finish}" />
```

It's pretty basic, but it's mostly what I need.  It only highlights the password box though, would like to get it to highlight both.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better custom validator that's more universal, clean, and works well with the 'required' field.

```
 import mx.validators.ValidationResult;
 import mx.validators.Validator;

 public class MatchValidator extends Validator{
  private var _matchSource: Object = null;
  private var _matchProperty: String = null;
  private var _noMatchError: String = "Fields did not match";

  [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="Fields did not match")]
  public function set noMatchError( argError:String):void{
   _noMatchError = argError;
  }
  public function get noMatchError():String{
   return _noMatchError;
  }

  [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="null")]
  public function set matchSource( argObject:Object):void{
   _matchSource = argObject;
  }
  public function get matchSource():Object{
   return _matchSource;
  }

  [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="null")]
  public function set matchProperty( argProperty:String):void{
   _matchProperty = argProperty;
  }
  public function get matchProperty():String{
   return _matchProperty;
  }


  override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {

   // Call base class doValidation().
   var results:Array = super.doValidation(value.ours);

   var val:String = value.ours ? String(value.ours) : "";
   if (results.length > 0 || ((val.length == 0) && !required)){
    return results;
   }else{
    if(val != value.toMatch){
     results.length = 0;
     results.push( new ValidationResult(true,null,"mismatch",_noMatchError));
     return results;
    }else{
     return results;
    }
   }
  }  

  override protected function getValueFromSource():Object {
   var value:Object = {};

   value.ours = super.getValueFromSource();

   if (_matchSource && _matchProperty){
    value.toMatch = _matchSource[_matchProperty];
   }else{
    value.toMatch = null;
   }
   return value;
  }
 }
```

Here's an example:

```
<components:MatchValidator source="{passwordCheckField}" property="text" matchSource="{passwordField}" matchProperty="text"
    valid="passwordsMatch = true" invalid="passwordsMatch = false" noMatchError="Passwords do not match"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done this in a different way using custom validation rules.

Check it out:
http://martypitt.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/rule-based-asynchronous-validation-in-flex-forms/

It shows how to do async validation (eg., checking a username is available on the server), and other validation scenario's that don't fit neatly into flex's out-of-the-box framework, including two passwords match.

Eg:

```
<mx:Button label="Register" enabled="{ validationRules.isValid }" />
<validation:ValidationRuleCollection id="validationRules">
      <validation:UsernameIsUniqueValidationRule username="{ txtUsername.text }" targetComponent="{ txtUsername }" />
      <validation:EmailIsUniqueValidationRule email="{ txtEmailAddress.text }" targetComponent="{ txtEmailAddress }" />
      <validation:PasswordsMustMatchValidationRule password1="{ txtPassword.text }" password2="{ txtPasswordConfirm.text }" targetComponent="{ txtPasswordConfirm }" />
      <mx:StringValidator required="true" source="{ txtUsername }" property="text" requiredFieldError="{ ResourceManager.getInstance().getString( ResourceBundles.ERROR_MESSAGES , 'REQUIRED_FIELD_ERROR' )}" />
</validation:ValidationRuleCollection>
```

Comment: Hey, I found a slight bug in your validation system. Basically the validation event handler wasn't wired for the standard flex validators.

I've fixed it by changing the validationRules setter in ValidationRuleCollection, adding the addEventListener :)

Comment: @Kel and @Marty Pitt , is this now fixed on [Marty's site](http://martypitt.wordpress.com)? I need to do this sort of asynchronous validation and this "framework" looks like just the thing! I'm just a bit nervous about trying to implement it, if there is a bug

Answer (score 1):

I expanded on Daniel's solution, adding the ability to trigger off of the matched source as well.

```
import flash.events.Event;

import mx.validators.ValidationResult;
import mx.validators.Validator;

public class MatchValidator extends Validator
{
    private var _matchSource: Object = null;
    private var _matchProperty: String = null;
    private var _noMatchError: String = "Fields did not match";

    [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="Fields did not match")]
    public function set noMatchError( argError:String):void{
        _noMatchError = argError;
    }
    public function get noMatchError():String{
        return _noMatchError;
    }

    [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="null")]
    public function set matchSource( argObject:Object):void{
        removeTriggerHandler();
        _matchSource = argObject;
        addTriggerHandler();
    }
    public function get matchSource():Object{
        return _matchSource;
    }

    [Inspectable(category="General", defaultValue="null")]
    public function set matchProperty( argProperty:String):void{
        _matchProperty = argProperty;
    }
    public function get matchProperty():String{
        return _matchProperty;
    }

    override protected function doValidation(value:Object):Array {

        // Call base class doValidation().
        var results:Array = super.doValidation(value.ours);

        var val:String = value.ours ? String(value.ours) : "";
        if (results.length > 0 || ((val.length == 0) && !required)){
            return results;
        }else{
            if(val != value.toMatch){
                results.length = 0;
                results.push( new ValidationResult(true,null,"mismatch",_noMatchError));
                return results;
            }else{
                return results;
            }
        }
    }  

    override protected function getValueFromSource():Object {
        var value:Object = {};

        value.ours = super.getValueFromSource();

        if (_matchSource && _matchProperty){
            value.toMatch = _matchSource[_matchProperty];
        }else{
            value.toMatch = null;
        }
        return value;
    }

    override public function set triggerEvent(value:String):void
    {
        removeTriggerHandler();
        super.triggerEvent = value;
        addTriggerHandler();
    }

    private function addTriggerHandler():void
    {
        if (_matchSource)
            _matchSource.addEventListener(triggerEvent,triggerHandler);
    }

    private function removeTriggerHandler():void
    {
        if (_matchSource)
            _matchSource.removeEventListener(triggerEvent,triggerHandler);
    }

    private function triggerHandler(event:Event):void
    {
        validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you *have* to use a validator, you can simply attach a change event handler and set `errorString` property of the password field when the passwords don't match. It gives the same highlighting as done by validator.